# printing a sudoku text file in a 9x9 board

Tags: arrays, file, text, sudoku

Good day,

I have a sudoku text file that i want to print in a 9x9 array board.

The text file goes like that :

001 012 023 034 045 056 067 078 089 ..... there are 81 chains of 3 numbers.

every chain of 3 numbers represent a number in a sudoku board ( row , column , value ).

I need help for writing a code that will read the 81 chain of numbers and assign them to a 9x9 sudoku board and print it. I got the code for reading and printing the text file but i can't figure out how to convert that sudoku text file format to a 9x9 board.

Thank you.

Comment: That feels like a very inefficient way to store a sudoku board unless you’re expecting it to be very sparse.

Comment: it's a work that i have to do. not my choice.

Comment: If each 3-number chain is `space` separated, then create a 2D array of `char chains[81][3];` (or `81x4` to treat each chain as a string). Read into the 2D array. Since all values are `[0-9]`, you can simply subtract `'0'` to get the numeric value from each digit. Then loop over your 81 array values and populate a 9x9 2D array with the `xyn` values (e.g. `x = array[i][0] - '0';` and `y = array[i][1] - '0';` and `value = array[i][2] - '0';`)

Comment: I need it in java, Thank you